# Periodic points of the dynamical system $(K,\varphi)$ and Periodic Maximal Ideals in its associated Koopman system $(C(K),T_{\varphi})$

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, c-star-algebras, ergodic-theory, koopman-operator

At the moment I am reading *Operator Theoretic Aspects of Ergodic Theory* by Eisner et al. and trying to understand the concept of periodicity and recurrence of points in terms of dynamical systems.

I want to understand why the following holds:

> Let $(K,\varphi)$ a topological dynamical system and $(C(K),T_{\varphi})$ the Koopman system. Also for a closed set $A\subseteq K$ let $I_A:=\{f\in C(K): f_{\mid A}=0\}$.
> Then it holds that a point $x\in K$ is periodic if and only if $T^{n}_\varphi I_{\{x\}}= I_{\{x\}}$.

I know that $x\in K$ is called periodic if there is $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\varphi^n(x)=x$. How can I use this information in the Koopman system and $T_\varphi$?

Comment: Hi! I was studying that book, and got quite far; I recall them talking about ideals $I_A$ of the $C$ space, but could you please reference exactly where this theorem is mentioned? I don’t remember taking notes on it

Comment: For reference purposes a more general statement is Lem.4.18 on p.54. I've added the adjective "maximal" in the title as it's covered in Lem.4.9 on p.50 that maximal ideals of $C(K)=C^0(K;\mathbb{C})$ are exactly the ideals made up of functions vanishing on singletons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\in K$ be fixed and $(K;\varphi),T_\varphi$ be defined as in the book.

Part one:

> If $n\in\Bbb N$ is such that $\varphi^n(x)=x$, then for any function $f$ defined on $K$, $T^n_\varphi(f)(x)=f(\varphi^n(x))=f(x)$ so $f(x)=0$ implies $T^n_\varphi(f)(x)=0$. Continuity or any topological considerations are irrelevant.

Part two:

> If $n\in\Bbb N$ is such that $T^n_\varphi(I_{\{x\}})=I_{\{x\}}$, then for all continuous functions $f:K\to\Bbb R$, $f(x)=0\implies f(\varphi^n(x))=0$. Suppose for contradiction that $\varphi^n(x)=y\neq x$. As $K$ is Hausdorff, compact (the book defines its dynamical systems like this deliberately!) and therefore normal, there exists, by Urysohn’s lemma (this is maybe overkill but it works in the context of the book) a continuous function $f$ with $f(x)=0,\,f(y)=1$ ($\{y\},\{x\}$ are disjoint and closed) which means $f\notin T^n_\varphi(I_{\{x\}})$ but $f\in I_{\{x\}}$, a contradiction, so $\varphi^n(x)=x$ must hold.